# How to get generated ID after I inserted into a new data record in database using Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: database, spring, unique, jdbctemplate, persistent

I got a very common question when I was using Spring JDBCTemplate, I want to get the ID value after I inserted a new data record into database, this ID value will be referred to another related table. I tried the following way to insert it, but I always return 1 rather than its real unique ID. (I use MySQL as the database)

```
public int insert(BasicModel entity) {
    String insertIntoSql = QueryUtil.getInsertIntoSqlStatement(entity);

    log.info("SQL Statement for inserting into: " + insertIntoSql);

    return this.jdbcTemplate.update(insertIntoSql);
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`JdbcTemplate.update()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update%28java.lang.String%29) returns:

> the number of rows affected

Which is always `1` for `INSERT` statement. Different databases support generated key extraction in different ways, but most JDBC drivers abstract this and `JdbcTemplate` supports this. Quoting [*12.2.8 Retrieving auto-generated keys*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys)

> An `update()` convenience method supports the retrieval of primary keys generated by the database. This support is part of the JDBC 3.0 standard; see Chapter 13.6 of the specification for details.

Basically you need this much more verbose statement:

```
final String insertIntoSql = QueryUtil.getInsertIntoSqlStatement(entity);
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

jdbcTemplate.update(
  new PreparedStatementCreator() {
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
      return connection.prepareStatement(insertIntoSql, new String[] {"id"});
    }
  }, keyHolder);

return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
```

Comment: Hi Tomasz, I try your method, but didnt work in my place. I work on it on long time but cant get the solution. Kindly advise 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567633/get-back-the-primary-key-value-after-insertion-to-db2-table-by-keyholder

Comment: How can we do the same in Batch update?

Answer (score 9):

You can use @Tomasz Nurkiewicz answer and it works for sure, but you don't need to :
Spring offers [SimpleJdbcInsert](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcInsert.html) which "provides meta-data processing to simplify the code needed to construct a basic insert statement".

```
@Repository
public class UserDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertIntoUser;

    @Autowired
    public UserDao(DataSource datasource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        insertIntoUser = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate).withTableName("user").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id_user");
    }

    public Number insertUser(User u) {
        final Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("name", u.getName());

        return insertIntoUser.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
    }
}
```

The "Number" returned by insertUser is the id_user generated for the user insertion.

Comment: Thanks, I liked this approach and it worked.

Comment: Documentation: [Simplifying JDBC Operations with the SimpleJdbc Classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/jdbc/simple.html)

Answer (score 7):

@panadol-chong, a small modification was necessary for @tomasz-nurkiewicz's code to work here.

```
final String SQL = "INSERT INTO ... RETUNING id";

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL, 
                           Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    return ps;
}, keyHolder);

return keyHolder.getKey().intValue();
```

The main difference is the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`.