# How to insert a row to DB in spring, using only auto-generated values, and return an ID?

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb, spring-jdbc, simplejdbcinsert

I use spring framework, and would like to insert a row to DB in order to have its ID, which is needed for further processing. 
Inserting query is given below, it's a simple query, without parameters. But it's even worse, cause how to construct working call using `executeAndReturnKey` from `SimpleJdbcInsert`? This is an SQL query for insert. But I don't know whether it is possible to use it within `simpleJdbcInsert` instance.

```
insert into sdc_import_run(id_import_run, create_date)
values(nextval('seq_import_run'),now())
```

I tried

```
Number genId = simpleJdbcInsert.withTableName("sdc_import_run")
            .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id_import_run")
            .executeAndReturnKey(new MapSqlParameterSource());
```

It doesn't work, the thing is, they want all parameters for the table, but I dont want any of them, I want to insert only auto-generated: `id_import_run` (primary key) and `create_date`. As a result I want to have the inserted ID in a variable. How would you do that?

**EDIT**
Such an approach works fine.

```
public Integer persistInsertImportRunForId(){
    String queryString = getSql("insertImportRunForId");
    KeyHolder holder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    jdbcTemplate.update(con -> {
            return con.prepareStatement(queryString, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        }, holder
    );

    return CommonUtils.tryOrGet(() -> holder.getKeys().get("id_import_run"), null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your complete insert SQL using [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). You can provide any SQL you'd like here, with as little or many columns defined for your insert as your table's DDL will allow.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537628/3259564) covers this in more details.